# Can a magus using spell combat use improved two weapon fighting with it?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, magic, magus

Im working on a new character and have been reading up on some of the classes.
I was reading the magus class and their [spell combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-) ability.

> At 1st level, a magus learns to cast spells and wield his weapons at the same time. This functions much like two-weapon fighting, but the off-hand weapon is a spell that is being cast.

Since you are allowed to use the spell for the purpose of two weapon fighting, does this open up the whole two weapon fighting tree?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spell combat *functions much like* two-weapon fighting, but is not the same thing.  Spell combat does not modify your ordinary full attack as two weapon-fighting does.  Instead, it describes a new full-round action that the magus can take:

> As a full-round action, he can make all of his attacks with his melee weapon at a –2 penalty and can also cast any spell from the magus spell list with a casting time of 1 standard action (any attack roll made as part of this spell also takes this penalty).

So feats that modify ordinary two-weapon fighting would not apply to spell combat.

Comment: I figured that would be the case, but cant blame a guy for trying